# How can I refresh the data source of ListAdapter at once after I launch submitList in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I use ListAdapter as the source of a RecyclerView, it will display a list of `MVoice`. The data source is `mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort`, it's `LiveData<List<MVoice>>`, you can see Code A.

After I added a record, `mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe` will be launched, `myAdapter.submitList(it)` will be launched too.

But I found, the latest `mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort` isn't applied to ListAdapter, you can see Log A.

How can I refresh the data source of ListAdapter at once after I launch submitList ?

**Log A**

```
E/My: itemCount: 13 it: 14 CurrentList:13
```

**Code A**

```
binding.recyclerViewVoice.adapter = myAdapter
mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
   myAdapter.submitList(it)
   Log.e("My","itemCount: "+myAdapter.itemCount+ " it: "+it.size+ " CurrentList:"+myAdapter.currentList.size)

}

class VoiceAdapters (private val aHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel, private val mPlay: PlayInterface):
        ListAdapter<MVoice, VoiceAdapters.VoiceViewHolder>(MVoiceDiffCallback()) {

    private lateinit var mContext: Context
    private lateinit var mLifecycleOwner:LifecycleOwner

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VoiceViewHolder {
        mContext = parent.context
        mLifecycleOwner = mContext as LifecycleOwner

        return VoiceViewHolder(
            LayoutVoiceItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false).also {              
               it.lifecycleOwner = mLifecycleOwner
               it.aHomeViewModel = aHomeViewModel
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VoiceViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val inputMVoice = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(inputMVoice)
    }

   
    inner class VoiceViewHolder (private val binding: LayoutVoiceItemBinding):
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
       
        fun bind(inputMVoice: MVoice) {                        
            binding.amVoice = inputMVoice          
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

}


class MVoiceDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MVoice>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MVoice, newItem: MVoice): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MVoice, newItem: MVoice): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

**Added Content**

To Tenfour04: Thanks!

The following Code B is how to get the LiveDate `mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort`.

**Code B**

```
class HomeViewModel(val mApplication: Application, private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {

    private val _listVoiceBySort=_sortBy.switchMap {
        mDBVoiceRepository.listVoiceBySort(it)
    }

    val listVoiceBySort: LiveData<List<MVoice>> =_listVoiceBySort
    ...
}

class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){

    private val _isHaveRecord= MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)
    val isHaveRecord:LiveData<Boolean> =_isHaveRecord

    fun listVoiceBySort(aSortBy: ESortBy): LiveData<List<MVoice>> {
        var query=when (aSortBy){
            ESortBy.StartPriority ->
               "SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY starred desc, createdDate desc"
            ESortBy.DateDesc ->
               "SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY createdDate desc"
            ESortBy.DateAsc ->
               "SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY createdDate"
            ESortBy.TitleDesc ->
               "SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY title desc"
            ESortBy.TitleAsc ->
               "SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY title"
        }
        return mDBVoiceDao.runtimeQuery(SimpleSQLiteQuery(query)).map {
            _isHaveRecord.value =!it.isNullOrEmpty()
            it
        }
    }
    ...
}

@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{   
   @RawQuery(observedEntities = [MVoice::class])
   fun  runtimeQuery(sortQuery: SupportSQLiteQuery): LiveData<List<MVoice>>
   ...
}


abstract class DBVoiceDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you update the value in the LiveData?

Comment: Thanks! I don't do any operation for updating the LiveDate `mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort` after I add a record, it seems that the system update the LiveData automatically.

Comment: Where does the live data instance come from? The reason I’m asking is that if you have a LiveData of a list, it doesn’t report changes to the underlying list to existing observers unless you manually trigger it to.

Comment: Thanks! I get  the LiveDate `mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort`  from ViewModel, it's a table of  SQLite with Room using @DAO.

Comment: Yes, but can you show the code? What's the DAO function you're calling? Does it return Flow or LiveData or just a List? How do you convert what it returns to LiveData?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: OK, I don't see any issues on that end. The only part of your code that I'm not sure about is data-binding the individual rows of data. Everything else looks fine to me, and I'm not familiar with data binding, so I'm thinking the issue is probably something to do with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`submitList()` is asynchronous. Calling other methods on `myAdapter` right away after `submitList()` may not reflect the list that you just submitted.

Instead, you could [override `onCurrentListChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter#oncurrentlistchanged) and look at the adapter at that point.

Or, just count the rows that you see on the screen.

Comment: Thanks! but `myAdapter.onCurrentListChanged(){previousList, currentList -> ...}` doesn't work

Comment: @HelloCW: I do not know what "doesn't work" means in this context. Regardless, your existing logging is not going to work either. If you need to be able to update the list contents synchronously, do not use `ListAdapter`. Instead, create your own `RecyclerView.Adapter` that does not use background threads for its work.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your submit code like

```
mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
   (binding.recyclerViewVoice.adapter as YourAdapter).submitList(it.map { it.copy() })
   Log.e("My","itemCount: "+myAdapter.itemCount+ " it: "+it.size+ " CurrentList:"+myAdapter.currentList.size)

}
```

You submit your list reference to adapter and when something changes it already have that changes inside adapter and diffutil can't find any differences. You can fix that issue with copy items of the list while submitting.

Comment: Thanks! But I get the same result just like "Log A" when I add record with your code.

Comment: Edited my answer can you check it again?

Comment: Thanks! I still get the same result just like "Log A" when I add record with your updated code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ListAdapter`, but change `submitList()` to submit list updates synchronously instead of async, you can create your own backing list and override a few methods like this:

```kotlin
inner class MyListAdapter() : ListAdapter<MyListItem, MyViewHolder>(MyDiffUtil) {
    private var currentList: List<MyListItem> = listOf()
    override fun getCurrentList(): List<MyListItem> = currentList
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = currentList.size
    override fun getItem(position: Int) = currentList[position]

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val binding = MyItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProjectViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(currentList[position])
    }

    override fun submitList(list: List<MyListItem>?) {
        submitList(list, null)
    }

    override fun submitList(list: List<MyListItem>?, commitCallback: Runnable?) {
        requireNotNull(list)

        //Your implementation of DiffUtil goes here. It will probably be the same as
        //MyDiffUtil in the first line of this code snippet.
        val diff = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {
            override fun getOldListSize() = currentList.size

            override fun getNewListSize() = list.size

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
                currentList[oldItemPosition].myItemId == list[newItemPosition].myItemId

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
                false

            override fun getChangePayload(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
                "Rebind-Payload"
        })

        diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
        currentList = list.toMutableList()

        commitCallback?.run()
    }
}
```

Note: this is an inner class, so that we can call `layoutInflater` on the `Fragment` where this is used.